# Hive layer on top of MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, hadoop, cluster-computing, hive

Disclaimer: I am a newbie w.r.t Hadoop and Hive.

We have set up a MySql Cluster (version 7.2.5) which stores huge amounts of data. The rows runs into millions and are partitioned based on Mysql's autosharding logic. Even though we are leveraging Adaptive Query Localization (AQL) of Cluster 7.2, some of our queries have multiple joins and runs into quite a few minutes and sometimes hours.

In this scenario, can I use Hive along with Hadoop to query the DB and retrieve the data? Will it make the querying faster? Does it duplicate the data in its file system? What are the pros and cons of this type of approach?

My intent is to use Hive as a layer on top of MySQL Cluster and use it for read/write from and to MySQL Cluster DB. I do not have any transactions in my application. So is this really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible. The closest solution in this direction known to me is :http://www.hadapt.com/ by Daniel Abadi. 
The idea of it solution to have local RDBMS on each node and run usual hadoop MR, and Hive on top of it on these nodes. 
In principle if you will do smart Hive integration and push down predicates to MySQL instances it can give you some performance gains. 
In the same time you should do some serious hacking to make hadoop to be aware of you sharding placement to preserve data locality. 
Summarizing all above - it should be possible but will require serious development. 
In the same time - I am not aware of out of the box solution to run hive over Mysql cluster as is.

Comment: So this looks like a long term project. So what is better here? Would using only hadoop with HDFS/HIVE help here in reducing the reading time, if we write our own MapReduce jobs.

Comment: i think simplest solution is to load data from MySQL to Hive/Hadoop and query it there. It will solve scalability problem and arise problem of latency - you can not keep data in hive cluster up to date.